# Why are histograms the same [python + simplecv]

Tags: python, histogram, simplecv

My question is why are the two histograms in following code the same.
Because the picture does change, first show shows original picture and second shows completely black picture.

Am I miss-using simpleCV or is this perhaps a bug?

Code:

```
from itertools import product
from SimpleCV import Image
from SimpleCV import Color

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

def number_of_hues(picture):
    image = Image(picture)

    #convert the picture's space to HSV
    image = image.toHSV()
    image.show()
    original_histogram = image.histogram()


    (image_x_length, image_y_length) = image.size()
    for i,j in product(range(image_x_length), range(image_y_length)):
        image[i,j] = Color.BLACK


    image.show()

    new_histogram =  image.histogram()

    for o,n in zip(original_histogram, new_histogram):
        if o != n:
            print o,n
```

Comment: It's working fine. I had updated my SimpleCV couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When was the last time you did a pull from the develop github repo? There was a bug in the set item call for the image class that kept images from getting set directly. It was fixed a couple weeks ago. Generally you should try to avoid directly looping over image objects and setting pixels directly as it can be really slow. If you think you found a bug please submit an issue to our github repo and we will try to address it as soon as we can.

Comment: I've installed simpleCV about 3 weeks ago, so I guess that is the bug you meantioned, but I will report it just in case.
And also thank you for your answer.